# Docker build with latest apt package is general?

Tags: docker

In my understanding, `docker build` usually use cache if Dockerfile seems not to be changed and not include `COPY` command, so if I do it with no option, Dockerfile which includes `apt-get` or `apt-get update`(or something similler command, you know) will be cached and never update package actually.
I want to use latest package for several library(for security purpose) so I always use `docker build` with `no cache` option.
On the other hand, there is `--mount=type=cache` option. It's not `docker build` option but `RUN` command option. I read document. this RUN option makes package managers possible to be cached.
So, maybe my approach is wrong? With docker, does it generally use cache and never (or slight few) update packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you not change the `Dockerfile` the cashe will always be used sure if the image is already downloaded locally.

your approch to use `--no-cache` is right.

on the other hand if you need to update the packages during the run time you may add `apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade` to your `ENTRYPOINT` in this case you update the packages every time the container starts.